# Why does Centos7 run /etc/profile.d scripts from both /etc/profile AND /etc/bashrc?

Tags: bash, centos, profile

Centos7 has the following in `/etc/profile`:

```bsh
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

AND the following in `/etc/bashrc` (which is run from `~/.bashrc`):

```bsh
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    done
```

Debian and Ubuntu only run these from `/etc/profile`, which is what I would expect.

- why does Centos run them from both ?
- why the disparity in `sh.local` ?

Comment: interesting observation.  interesting the difference in how they check for interactive shells, too.

Comment: i think the interactive test difference is probably due to one being bash-only and the other being sh-alikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure on the first question, but I assume the reasons for it is Debian-based shell acts "dumber" by default when called as `sh` than Red Hat-based ones; they act like `bash` even when called as `sh`.

This [Red Hat bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1344007) explains that `sh.local` is for the SA to override *everything* else found in `/etc/profile.d`.